# How to select multiple entries in a dropdown menu c#

Tags: c#

Can not select (check) multiple menuitems in dropdown menu.

There are 2 dropdown menus where I would like to select more than one entry in each of them. In designer view it does not have an option to do so, am I missing something?

Comment: What technology are you talking about? Is this WebForms / WindowsForms / WPF?

Comment: Set the Checked property.

Comment: Do you just mean select? You say "select (check)", but they are not the same action. Usually when someone mentions checking a control, it's either related to a `CheckBox` or `RadioButton` (or similar control).

Comment: I think you forgot to add code. Please edit and add what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

Specify what technology you're talking about.

In the case of ASP.NET WebForms, use `ListBox` with `SelectionMode` set to `Multiple` instead of `DropDownList`:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Text="SelectionText" Value="1" />
</asp:ListBox>
```

In the case of WindowsForms, use `ListView` with `MultiSelect` set to true or `ListBox` with `SelectionMode` set to either `MultiSimple` or `MultiExtended` based on your case.

For WPF you have `ListBox` with `SelectionMode` with options of `Multiple` and `Extended` once again.

```
<ListBox Name="lb" SelectionMode="Extended">
  <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```